# Probability where you can win or lose at any point in the game

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

Say that you had a game where there are two players taking turns rolling a 10 sided die. Player A rolls first.

When Player A is rolling:
If player A rolls a 1, Player A wins.
If Player A rolls a 2 or 3, Player B wins.
If Player A rolls a 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10, then Player B rolls.

When Player B is rolling:
If Player B rolls a 1 or 2, Player B wins.
If Player B rolls a 3, 4, or 5, Player A wins.
If Player B rolls a 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10, then Player A rolls.

What is the probability of Player A winning the game?

I'm not sure how to sum up the infinite series. Probability where A wins on their turn would be .1 + (.7)(.5)(.1) + (.7)^2 (.5)^2 (.1) + (.7)^3 (.5)^3 (.1)...     and then need to add the probability that A wins on B's turn. That would be (.7)(.3) + (.7)^2 (.5)(.3) + (.7)^3 (.5)^2 (.3)...

Comment: I'm not sure how to sum up the infinite series. Probability where A wins on their turn would be .1 + (.7)(.5)(.1) + (.7)^2 (.5)^2 (.1) + (.7)^3 (.5)^3 (.1)...     and then need to add the probability that A wins on B's turn. That would be (.7)(.3) + (.7)^2 (.5)(.3) + (.7)^3 (.5)^2 (.3)...

Comment: You should add this to your question. otherwise the question will be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important point is that if both players do not win or lose on the first two rolls, you are back at the start.  Let $a$ be the probability player $A$ wins.  He wins if he wins on the first roll or does not lose on the first roll and either $B$ loses on the second or he wins the new game.  So
$$a=\frac 1{10}+\frac 7{10}\frac 3{10}+\frac 7{10}\frac5{10}a$$
where the first term is the immediate win, the second is passing on the first and $B$ loses on the second, and the third is returning to start.  This gives
$$\frac{65}{100}a=\frac {31}{100}\\a=\frac{31}{65}$$